# Repeatedly, when I use `conda` my computer doesn't know what the command is

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I'm using an Ubuntu 17.04 machine.

I installed Anaconda a while ago and it worked fine.  The next day, I'd issue a `conda` command at the terminal and it would say the command was not recognized.  I figured I must have done something wrong, uninstalled, reinstalled, and it worked fine again.  The whole cycle repeated about a month ago:  Issue the command, am told it's not recognized, reinstall, now it works.  With some confusion and futzing I came to the possibly mistaken conclusion that I had to be in a certain directory to get the command to work--I guess maybe there was some PATH issue that I wasn't understanding.  But I figured, fine, if I run into this again I'll just navigate to the appropriate folder.  Now today, I issue a conda command, even in the folder where it usually works, and it doesn't work.

So I've again deleted all of my Anaconda folders and files, i.e.

```
sudo rm -rf /home/usrnm/anaconda3
```

and I'm about to reinstall but I'm getting tired of the constant need to reinstall.  Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?  I've found that when I echo `sys.path` I get

```
.path
```

and when I echo `PATH` I get

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

[Edit: A possibly more specific question is, is there somewhere in particular I should be saving the installer that I download from their website?  I always just download it to `~/Downloads` and leave it there, trusting that the installer will create all of the necessary files and folders for smooth running elsewhere.]

Answer (score 0):

You do not have that anaconda3 directory in your $PATH, this is the problem.

Edit the file `/home/username/.bashrc` and add this to the end:

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

That should ensure the `conda` command is always in your $PATH and you can always access it no matter what directory you are in.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux it does not matter which directory you are in when executing commands. All commands must be on the `PATH` (or builtin as part of your shell). Assuming that you are using bash (or similar), you can place anaconda on your `PATH` by executing

```
export PATH="/path/to/anaconda/bin:${PATH}"
```

This has to be done each time you open up a new terminal. To make your shell do this for you, place the above code in your `.bashrc` file, placed in your home folder (this may or may not already exist).

Comment: So the following is already on the `.bashrc` file:  `# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`  Should I change this to what you have?

Comment: No that should be fine. It is odd that `/home/addem/anaconda3/bin` does not show up when you do `echo $PATH` though. Are you sure that you are using the bash shell? And does it work if you manually run `export PATH="/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`?